# Oracle SQL order by Varchar2 with '_'

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I've got a table with a varchar2 column. Sorting by that column did not give me the expected result:

```
with test (col) as
  (select '_83_' from dual union all
   select '_81_' from dual union all
   select '4___' from dual union all
   select '____' from dual
  )
select * from test
order by col desc;
```

returns:

```
Col 
1. '_83_'
2. '_81_'
3. '4___'
4. '____'
```

I did expect:

```
Col 
1. '4___'
2. '_83_'
3. '_81_'
4. '____'
```

Can you explain this and help me to get `'4___'` to the start of my order by statement?

Edit Using Littlefoots statement for preproduceabillity...

Edit I am using Oracle 12c

Edit NLS_Sort is set to German language. This was the issue.

Comment: Can you put sample data and expected output also, this is hard to suggest anything with less information.

Comment: You can set NLS_SORT to binary or use `order by nlssort(column1, 'NLS_SORT = BINARY') desc`, but I do not know why Oracle ignores underscores by default.

Comment: What is the current value of your NLS_SORT setting?

Comment: @PonderStibbons because oracle ignores underscores if the sort setting is a linguistic one. ASCII table based sorting or BINARY define different sorting rules for underscores to linguistic NLS_SORTs

Comment: @CaiusJard - yes, I see it on examples, but cannot find this information in Oracle docs.

Comment: @PonderStibbons like this, you mean? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch5lingsort.htm

Comment: My NLS_SORT was set to German. This caused the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my local database, `NLS_SORT` is set to `BINARY` so It is not reproducible.

```
WITH TEMO AS 
(
SELECT '_83_' AS X FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '_81_' AS X FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '4___' AS X FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '____' AS X FROM DUAL
)
SELECT * FROM TEMO ORDER BY X DESC;

X   
----
____
_83_
_81_
4___
```

But, after changing `NLS_SORT` from `BINARY` to `GERMAN`, the issue is reproduced.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT=GERMAN;

WITH TEMO AS 
(
SELECT '_83_' AS X FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '_81_' AS X FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '4___' AS X FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '____' AS X FROM DUAL
)
SELECT * FROM TEMO ORDER BY X DESC;

X   
----
_83_
_81_
4___
____
```

You can check the NLS values using the following table:

```
NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS
```

so the conclusion is `NLS_SORT` parameter must be set accordingly because not everyone wants to sort using technique.

**Default value of `NLS_SORT`** is derived from `NLS_LANGUAGE`.

Refer [oracle documents](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams130.htm#REFRN10127) for more information about NLS_SORT.

Solution is to change `NLS_SORT` according to requirement.

Cheers!!

Comment: You found it :-)

...
But, after changing NLS_SORT from BINARY to GERMAN, the issue is reproduced....

Comment: You can change nls_sort value to null and can assign value to  as AMERICAN to nls_language. v$parameter
Name =nls_sort and value =null
name =nls_language and value=AMERICAN

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question. Yes, a comment would be more appropriate but I can't post this:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '_83_' from dual union all
  3     select '_81_' from dual union all
  4     select '4___' from dual union all
  5     select '____' from dual
  6    )
  7  select * from test
  8  order by col;

COL
----
____
4___
_81_
_83_

SQL>
```

As you can see, my results differ from yours, i.e. I can't reproduce what you are saying. Could you explain it once again, please?

Comment: My result is also different
4___
_81_
_83_
____

Comment: @MansiRaval you mean your result is different to littlefoot?

Comment: You run:  order by col; I run:  order by col desc;

Comment: but you and I have 4___ in between  ____ and  _ 81 _   this is the part that I dont get... I expected what Mansi Raval got....

Comment: @CaiusJard yes the ______ is last in my case.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=eeef66e18fd5867edccf7e4d54a07006  '4___'  and  '____' are top / bottom items depending on ASC / DESC

Comment: No @Serg , it is beacause of NLS parameters. in my system nls_sort value is null and default value it taking from nls_language parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Using Oracle 11g R2:

```sql
Select Column1 From (
    SELECT CAST( '_83_' AS varchar2(4) ) AS Column1 FROM dual
    union all
    SELECT CAST( '_81_' AS varchar2(4) ) AS Column1 FROM dual
    union all
    SELECT CAST( '4___' AS varchar2(4) ) AS Column1 FROM dual
    union all
    SELECT CAST( '____' AS varchar2(4) ) AS Column1 FROM dual
) A order by Column1  desc
```

Output:

```
____
_83_
_81_
4___
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd recommend Tejash's answer but you can also fudge it with something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY TRANSLATE(col, '_', 'z') desc;
```